# Given a phrase, how to determine whether it is a name?

Tags: algorithm, text, machine-learning, nlp, pattern-recognition

Given a phrase, such as 'Michael Jordan' or 'Software Engineering'. Is there any way to determine whether it is a name or not?

Any Research or Library API or Online Tools to do that?

Comment: i dont see a better solution than labelling potential names and testing against these names, since naming is a semantic concept and not merely syntactic

Comment: Without properly defining the concept of a `name`, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: So do you consider Software Engineering a name or not? Any NER tool would label Michael Jordan as PER (Person Named Entity)

Answer (score 2):

If your phrases come with contexts, you can use any NERC (named enitity recognition and classification) tool like [Standford](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml), [Lingpipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/ne/read-me.html) or others. You can choose what types of names do you want - e.g. Persons, Organizations, Locations, and so on.

If you have only phrases as text strings, then I can only propose to use existed dictionaries. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1803628/4588780) about list of person names; you can also try to determine if the word is presented in ordinary dictionaries (like [Oxford dictionary](http://oxford-dictionary-of-english.en.malavida.com/)), because they rarely contain proper names.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could potentially use https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/name/ for what you are looking for.